# How can I see the actual numerical output RGB values of the cycles 'Blackbody' node? (preferably through api)

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

More generally, using the Blackbody node as an example, how can I access the current numerical values of inputs, parameters/settings and outputs of cycles nodes, through the api or by other means?

In this particular case I want to compare the conversion values calculated by the Blackbody node with other color temperature -> RGB algorithms. But I'm interested in the more general situation. If this is not possible, shouldn't it be, and will it be in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for the compositor node which is present by default:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.use_nodes = True

nt = scene.node_tree

#get the node
node = nt.nodes['Composite']

#access by string key in 2.69
input = node.inputs['Alpha'].default_value = 0.5

#older versions of blender might require
#access by index
for index, input in enumerate(node.inputs):
    if input.name == "Alpha":
        print(index)
        break

#link    
output = nt.nodes['Render Layers'].outputs['Alpha']
nt.links.new(input, output)
```

You can hover over the input with python tooltips enabled:
[image: hover python tooltip]

Using python it is only possible to setup the tree and its parameters.

Via OSL you can implement your own shaders. Enable *Open Shading Language* in the render menu, add a script node and see *Text Editor* -> *Templates* -> [*Open Shading Language*](http://www.openshading.com/)

Template *Temperature To RGB*

```
shader temperature_to_rgb(
    float Kelvin = 1200.0,
    output color Color = 0.8)
{   
    /* Kelvin to RGB */
    Color = blackbody(Kelvin);
}
```

As you can see `blackbody` is an inbuilt function of the standard library.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I thought the OP was asking how to *view* the values of a node socket?

Comment: Thanks for this. I had more or less figured out this much. By "using python it is only possible to setup the tree and its parameters" I take it that accessing the actual current values of nodes (e.g. the RGB values from the Blackbody node output) is not possible. Why isn't this data exposed to python?

Comment: Because python is quite slow. As written above you can write and use your own OSL shaders in cycles.

Comment: OK, thanks. It surprises me that "too slow" is a reason for not being able to simply read off the current values of a node output of something like the blackbody node, which apparently just does some straightforward math / lookup. But I have further questions about the behavior of the blackbody node and will ask about this separately.

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but perhaps the reason for this is the RGB values of the blackbody node are actually computed by cycles at rendertime?